# How can I let my code return True or False based on the criteria set?

Tags: python, list

I asked this before but since I didn't get a very clear response as to where I should  change my code, I'm gonna ask this here again :)

So I'm trying to analyze my list h and see whether for x in that list, are their two pairs of the first character in the elements or not

So for instance,

```
['AS', 'AD', 'CC', 'CH', 'CS'] returns False because there are 3 C and 2 , but there are supposed to be 2 of the same elements and one of a completely different element.

['AS', 'AD', 'SC', 'SH', 'CS'] returns True because there are 2 A, 2 S and one C.
['CS', 'CD', 'AC', 'AH', 'FS'] returns True because there are 2 C, 2 A and one F

['AS', 'CD', 'AC', 'CH', 'DS'] returns False because although there are two A, two C and one D, the A and C are not in order
```

Here is my code so far...

```
def two_pairs(h):
    for x in h:
        pairing = list[x[1]]
        if (pairing[1] == pairing[2]) and (pairing[3] == (pairing[4])):
            return True
        if (pairing[3] == pairing[4]) and (pairing[0] == (pairing[1])):
            return True
        if (pairing[0] == pairing[1]) and (pairing[3] == (pairing[4])):
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(two_pairs(['9r, 9♣, 4♠, 4♣, 10♣']))
```

This doesn't really work at all and I'm getting an error message that says

```
if (pairing[1] == pairing[2]) and (pairing[3] == (pairing[4])):
TypeError: There are no type variables left in list['r']
```

What should I change??

Note: the back characters can be anything from numbers to letters to special characters.

Comment: `h` is a list of a string. This makes `x` a single string, so, what are you expecting `list[x[1]]` to do?

Answer (score 0):

`h` is a list of a string. This makes `x` a single string

Therefore `x[1] == 'r'` and `list()` is a built-in Python function that you are indexing with `list['r']`, which is not valid syntax for what you seem to want to do.

The answer you accepted in the previous post seemed to do what you want, and the input was a *list of strings*, not a list of one string.

e.g. Start with `print(two_pairs(['9r', '9♣', '4♠', '4♣', 10♣']))`, however none of these string have more than two characters, so it is going to still fail around `pairing[2]`, for example

> are their two pairs of the first character in the elements or not

Start with this

```
l = ['AS', 'AD', 'CC', 'CH', 'CS'] 
first = l[0][0]
print(2 == sum(x.count(first) for x in l))  # True
```

Or maybe

```
l = ['AS', 'AD', 'CC', 'CH', 'CS']
firsts = [x[0] for x in l]
print({f: sum(x.count(f) for x in l) for f in firsts})  # {'A': 2, 'C': 4}
```